# Grunt bump package.json version

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to add 'release' task:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  shell: {
    release: {
      command: function(version) {
        return 'git checkout -b release-' + version + ' devel';
      }
    }
  }
  ...
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bumpup');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  ...
  grunt.registerTask('release', function() {
    grunt.task.run('bumpup');
    var version = grunt.config.get('pkg').version;
    grunt.task.run('shell:release:' + version);
  });
```

But I have the following:

```
Running "release" task

Running "bumpup" task
Bumped to: 1.2.5

Running "shell:release:1.2.4" (shell) task
Switched to a new branch 'release-1.2.4'
M   Gruntfile.js
M   package.json
M   src/manifest.json

Done, without errors.
```

So the version was bumped up, but branch was created for previous version.

I think it is because package.json cached. Can I reread it?

```
 var version = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json').version; // old version too
```

**EDIT:**

Adding 'updateProps' to bumpup config will change pkg version property, but:

```
grunt.registerTask('release', function() {
  grunt.task.run('bumpup');

  var version = grunt.config.get('pkg').version;
  grunt.log.writeln(version); // old version, because tasks run async?

  grunt.task.run('shell:release:' + version);
});
```

Works good:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  ...
  bumpup: {
    options: {
      updateProps: {
        pkg: 'package.json'
      }
    },
    files: ['package.json', 'src/manifest.json']
  },
  shell: {
    release: {
      command: function() {
        return 'git checkout -b release-' + grunt.config.get('pkg').version + ' devel';
      }
    }
  },
  ...
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bumpup');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  ...
  grunt.registerTask('release', ['lint', 'bumpup', 'shell:release']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure to have set the `updateProps` option of the *grunt-bumpup* plugin? This will allow you to specify files to update with the new bumped version after your `bumpup` task is completed

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  bumpup: {
    options: {
      updateProps: {
        pkg: 'package.json'
      }
    },
    file: 'package.json'
  }
  ...
});
```